# Java Swing: get a random JButton from an ArrayList of JButtons

Tags: java, random

I have some buttons in an ArrayList, I want to choose a random one, I tried this code but I don't know how to fix it

```
ArrayList<JButton> vide = new ArrayList<JButton>();
Random btn = new Random();
vide.get(btn.next(btn.size()));
btn.setText("O");
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is not correct since you are trying to set the text on a Random object (an instance of the random class)

```
List<JButton> vide = new ArrayList<>();
Random btn = new Random();
vide.get(btn.nextInt(vide.size())).setText("O");
```

Comment: why would you want to shuffle an entire `List` when you need a random element? It seems totally unnecessary for the requirements.

Comment: the shuffle code works but the random one generate me the same syntaxe error : "size undefined" !!  I tried length, same error

Comment: I agree @Jack, thanks for the comment, the bigger the list the harder to shuffle : )

Comment: change `btn.size()` to `vide.size()`

Comment: I get a message `next(int) has protected access in java.util.Random` so i have to change to `btn.nextInt(...)`